# How can AA elite members get upgraded on a domestic codeshare?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs, american-airlines, code-share, alaska-airlines

I have a question about US domestic round trip travel. The flight is operated by American, but marketed by Alaska Airlines (AS) and the ticket is issued on AS stock (027). The passenger has Platinum status with AAdvantage, one benefit of which is complimentary cabin upgrades on domestic flights. The passenger has no status with Mileage Plan.

Can that passenger request a complimentary status upgrade on the AA-operated, AS-marketed flight? Which airline would the passenger contact?

Comment: Please expand the following abbreviations: RT, AS, AA, FF, pax.  Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to make your question more readable, but if I have misrepresented any thing, please do not hesitate to rollback and [edit] it yourself.

Comment: @choster Reopening due to your edits. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Frequent flyer privileges and points earned are based on the marketing carrier's rules, not the operating carrier.  You are not "flying" on an American Airlines ticket, therefore you are not an American Airlines "customer" on that flight.

Comment: Well.....here's the deal.  An agent very familiar with Sabre might be able to set this up by changing accrual and benefit programs on the res.  However, since it is an AS marked flight, they would probably only consider this if there are left over F seats *after* all AA coded flyers have been upgraded.